# Activity não abre apos a thread

Tags: android

Estou em um projeto Android e tenho uma activity que não abre, bem partindo da minha activity principal eu já tenho um botão que chama uma outra e tudo ocorre como esperado consigo fazer a transição de uma para outra sem problemas mais não sei o que ocorre com esta outra que eu chamo mais não aparece, inclusive já troquei ela com a outra que esta sendo chamada e ai ela aparece, bem mais vamos aos eventos para que se alguem puder me ajudar... eu tenho um WS e na minha activity principal dois campos usuario e senha, ao clicar no botão de login chamo uma thread que ira acessar o WS se conseguir logar então terei que chamar a SincronizarActivity, esta tem a finalidade de fazer uma sincronização ou seja importar alguns cadastros mais ela não aparece e nem no logcat algo indica algum erro.
Bem um pouco de código poderá então explicar melhor.

```
private void login(String login, String senha) {
    soap = new SoapObject(namespace,METHOD_NAME ); 

    PropertyInfo p1 = new PropertyInfo();
    PropertyInfo p2 = new PropertyInfo();
    p1.setName("Usuario");
    p1.setValue(login);
    p1.setType(String.class);
    p2.setName("Senha");
    p2.setValue(senha);
    p2.setType(String.class);

    soap.addProperty(p1);
    soap.addProperty(p2);

    envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soap);
    transporte = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);

    progress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Logando", "Aguarde...", true, false);

    Thread th = new Thread(MainActivity.this);
    th.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {

    try {

        transporte.call("", envelope);
        //resposta = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        objRetorno = envelope.getResponse();

        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Erro", "Erro: "+ e.getMessage());
        finish();
    }

}

private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        progress.dismiss();

        String[] parts = objRetorno.toString().split("#");

        if (Boolean.parseBoolean(parts[0])) {
            edtRetorno.setText("Ok ! "+parts[2]);
            criarsessao(parts);
        } else {
            edtRetorno.setText("Acesso negado! "+parts[1]);
        }

    }
};
```

Bem e para finalizar o metodo que chama a activity

```
private void criarsessao(String[] dados){
    sessaoUsuario = new SessaoUsuario();

    sessaoUsuario.setUsuario(edtUserName.getText().toString());
    sessaoUsuario.setSenha(edtPassWord.getText().toString());
    sessaoUsuario.setId(Integer.parseInt(dados[1]));
    sessaoUsuario.setNome(dados[2].toString());

    sessaoUsuarioService.criarSessao(sessaoUsuario);

    config = confService.BuscaporId(1);

    if (config.getSinc().toString() == "S"){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SincronizarActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Então se alguém puder me dar uma força agradeço.

Comment: Use o debug para saber o que acontece, cheque os métodos `criarsessao` e o método `onCreate` da activity `SincronizarActivity` para  debugar. Temos duas opções provaveis, 1ª uma das condições para abrir a nova atividade não está sendo verdadeira, ou 2ª algum erro acontece no onCreate da atividade a ser chamada

Comment: Prezados boa tarde, eu sai sim debugando tudo, mais o problema esta no If onde eu testo o config.getSinc() ali eu estou usando o operador ==, mudei e coloquei o método equals e então solucionei o problema.